# convert windows Laptap to a smartphone to run viber and whatsapp

Tags: chat

I have a Windows8.1 on laptap and a 3G Simcard modem.

Is there any way or any software to install some software like viber and whatsapp on my system?
I want to change my system to an smartphone..
Before I used BlueStack but viber do not support it now!

I am thinking something like wmware....but I do not know how is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

[Viber for Windows](http://www.viber.com/en/products/windows) lets you send free messages and make free calls to other Viber users, on any device and network, in any country! Viber syncs your contacts, messages and call history with your mobile device.
 I have tested it and it works fine.

You can continue to use BlueStack or use YouWave for Android Home for your whatsapp.